# How do I get ElasticSearch to honor non-dot expander notation for queries?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

[ElasticSearch 5.5.1]

I dynamically build elasticsearch queries (in js/node.js using npm elasticsearch) and I've found that part of the pain of doing that is that I have to initialize the deeply nested objects before assignment (obviously). To simplify the coding of this, I created a helper function that auto-initializes all of the intermediate objects if they don't exist.

```
function esqAssign(esq, keyPath, value) { }
let esq = {};
esqAssign(esq, 'bool.must.range.timestamp.gte', <timestamp>)
==>
esq = { bool: { must: { range { timestamp: { gte: <timestamp> }}}}}}
```

This works great ***unless*** I have a field that uses the dot-expander syntax like:

```
esqAssign(esq, 'bool.filter.term.myfield.id', <id>)
=>
esq = { bool: { filter: { term: { myfield: { id: <id> }}}}}
```

which fails when I do the actual query. However, this works

```
esq = { bool: { filter: { term: { "myfield.id": <id> }}}}}
```

my index schema contains:

```
...
"myfield": {  
  "properties": {  
      "id": {  
        "type": "long"
      },
   }
 }
```

To keep my code simple and not make the function signature `esqAssign(esq, keyName, prop, value)`, I would like to avoid the dot-expander notation.

If I look at this from a curl perspective, I'm wondering why this works:

```
curl localdev:9200/myindex/mytype/_search -XPOST  -d '{ "query": { "bool": { "filter": { "term": { "myfield.id": 1234 } } } } }'
```

and this doesn't:

```
curl localdev:9200/ myindex/mytype /_search -XPOST  -d '{ "query": { "bool": { "filter": { "term": { "myfield": { "id": 1234 } } } } } }'

{  
  "error":{  
     "root_cause":[  
        {  
           "type":"parsing_exception",
           "reason":"[term] query does not support [id]",
           "line":1,
           "col":69
        }
     ],
     "type":"parsing_exception",
     "reason":"[term] query does not support [id]",
     "line":1,
     "col":69
  },
  "status":400
}
```

Any ideas on how to have ES accept { myfield: { id ...} instead of requiring { myfield.id: ...}?